# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, i have this component **SidebarMenu** from the drawerContent of Drawer.Navigator

```js
    const SidebarMenu: React.FC<SidebarMenuProps> = (props) => {
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    
          <DocenteMenu />
    
          <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <View style={styles.itemContent}>
              <MenuItem label="Home" icon="home" pageName="Home" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Chamada eletrônica" icon="edit" pageName="CallList" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Horário aula" icon="calendar" pageName="ClassSchedule" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Diário eletrônico" icon="book-open" pageName="ClassDiary" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Agendamento prova" icon="file-plus" pageName="TestSchedule" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Relação de alunos" icon="users" pageName="StudentsList" {...props} />
              <MenuItem label="Holerite" icon="file-text" pageName="Payslip" {...props} />
            </View>
          </DrawerContentScrollView>
    
          <View style={styles.logoutContent}>
            <MenuItem label="Sair" icon="log-out" />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    export default SidebarMenu;
```

and I'm trying return a view from component **DocenteMenu** but its in that moment who returns a error. I alredy try to transform this function into "export default function" and return same error

```js
interface TeacherProps {
  COD_FUNCIONARIO: string,
  NOME_FUNC: string;
  DTA_NASC: Date;
  CPF: string;
  FOTO: string;
}
const DocenteMenu = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState<TeacherProps | null>();

  useEffect(function setUserProps() {

    const {docente} = useAuth();

    setUser(docente);

  }, []);

  return(
    <View style={styles.teacherInfo}>
      <Image
        style={styles.avatar}
        source={{ uri: user?.FOTO }}
      />
        <Text style={styles.teacherName}>{user?.NOME_FUNC}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.teacherCode}>{user?.COD_FUNCIONARIO }</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default DocenteMenu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Hooks have to be called in top level of `Function Component` or `another custom hook` so change your code to this and you good to go:

```
const { docente } = useAuth();
useEffect(function setUserProps() {
  setUser(docente);
}, []);
```

also read the official documents about rules of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

and this is a best practice just to use a simple callback for `useEffect` and don't give it a name like this:

```
const { docente } = useAuth();
useEffect(() => {
  setUser(docente);
}, []);
```

Comment: I put the name setUserProps trying to make work, but thanks, you saved my life. Can i ask u one more thing?

Comment: Greet, sure go on

Comment: @JuliaKimura I also gave you some upVotes to be free of minimum reputation rule. hope having fun with that :)

Comment: Thank u, that helps me alot. About the other thing, i have another error "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined", in this render https://imgur.com/a/Dr6XAE0, and im pretty new with react

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qhh2yUE this its the component who are returning error

Comment: @JuliaKimura This usually happens when you don't `export` your component or you `import` it incorrectly. or some times the return value is incorrect. you need to check all of these

Comment: @JuliaKimura I don't know what's your project structure looks like so I can't tell, you need to check this by yourself